# Grouping objects into a period of time to produce minimal groups

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have a collection of objects which contain a DateTime property, `DueDate`.

I wish to group these objects so that

- the `DueDate` properties are all within an hour of each other (not the same hour *per se*, but within 60 minutes of each other
- the least number of groups (each object should appear in only one group).

I currently have this, but it groups by the *hour number*, not a period of 60 minutes:

```
var interval = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);  // 1 hour
var groupedByDueDateHour in from job in jobs
                                 group job by job.DueDate.Value.Ticks / interval.Ticks
                                 into g
                                 select g)
```

How can I group by a *window of time* in order to produce a minimal number of groups?

Comment: So, if you have a Job A with DueDate = "14:50", Job B with DueDate = "13:51" and Job C with DueDate = "12:52" How do you group these records?

Comment: @Steve in that case there would be three groups. This is a minimum cover problem.

Comment: @Steve - in those cases there should be 2 groups: [12:52, 13:52] and [14:50].

Comment: @awj Oops sorry. I missed that the hours in Steve's example went the other way. You cannot do this with "groupby" since groupby requires that keys all be independent, but in your case, the key is dependent upon the values of neighbors. A simple greedy algorithm should work for this specific problem.

Comment: Are you using `00-24` as the window timeframe, or is it a calculation based on the lowest time in your collection?

Comment: @awj surely it would be 12.52 and 13.52+14.50 as there last is 2 mins closer

Comment: @BugFinder - you're quite right, there are two possible valid groups. Both options would be a group of 1 and another of 2.

Comment: @BugFinder My initial comment used "13:51" not "13:52" on purpose to highlight a missing case in the specs. The DueTime are at the exact interval of 59mins, now we should group starting from the highest time or from the lowest?

Comment: @Steve - Probably the lowest would be preferable though I don't have a good, technical reason for either lowest or highest (for my ultimate purpose). I suppose lowest would _appear_ to make sense to anyone looking at the results.

Comment: Did you require to use linq group or a brute force attack is good enough?

Comment: Linq might be more readable but a suggestion in any form is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brute force approach, probably there is a more elegant Linq solution but this seems to be correct

```
public class Job
{ 
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
}

// You need to have this list ordered by DueDate....
List<Job> myJobs = new List<Job>
{
    new Job{ID = 6, Name = "Job6", DueDate = new DateTime(2019,11,6,0,0,0)},
    new Job{ID = 7, Name = "Job7", DueDate = new DateTime(2019,11,6,0,0,0)},

    new Job{ID = 1, Name = "Job1", DueDate = new DateTime(2019,11,6,12,52,0)},
    new Job{ID = 2, Name = "Job2", DueDate = new DateTime(2019,11,6,13,51,0)},
    new Job{ID = 3, Name = "Job3", DueDate = new DateTime(2019,11,6,14,50,0)},
    new Job{ID = 4, Name = "Job4", DueDate = new DateTime(2019,11,6,15,49,0)},
};

Dictionary<int, List<Job>> grouped = new Dictionary<int, List<Job>>();

foreach (Job j in myJobs)
{
    int key = j.DueDate.Hour * 60 + j.DueDate.Minute;
    if(key == 0) key = -1; // for distinguish jobs due at midnight.
    int v = grouped.Keys.FirstOrDefault(k => (key - k) <= 60);
    if (v == 0)
        grouped.Add(key, new List<Job>(new Job[] { j}));
    else
        grouped[v].Add(j);
}
```

This should give back a dictionary where each key is the DueDate minutes from midnight and each value is a list of Jobs that are in the 60 minute range from the key

**To be tested with your real data**

Answer (score 0):

To create a more Linqy solution you could start by creating a generic grouping method that groups consecutive elements of a sequence, based on user-defined criteria. Below is a simple implementation of such a method:

```
public static IEnumerable<List<TSource>> GroupConsecutive<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, IList<TSource>, bool> predicate)
{
    List<TSource> list = null;
    IList<TSource> readOnlyList = null;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (list == null || !predicate(item, readOnlyList))
        {
            if (list != null) yield return list;
            list = new List<TSource>();
            readOnlyList = new ReadOnlyCollection<TSource>(list);
        }
        list.Add(item);
    }
    if (list != null) yield return list;
}
```

The `predicate` is a lambda that accepts the current element along with the current group, and should return a boolean value designating if the element belongs to the group or not. `true` means that it belongs to the group, and `false` means that it doesn't belong, so that the current group has been completed and a new one should be created, containing initially only the current element.

Then you could use this method to solve your initial problem, by sorting the objects by `DueDate` and then grouping them comparing the `DueDate` of each one with the `DueDate` of the first element of the current group. If the `TimeSpan` is less or equal to 60 minutes then the element belongs to the current group. This algorithm should produce the minimal amount of groups.

```
var source = new List<(int Id, DateTime DueDate)>();
source.Add((1, new DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 30, 0)));
source.Add((2, new DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 40, 0)));
source.Add((3, new DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 3, 20, 0)));
source.Add((4, new DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 4, 10, 0)));
source.Add((5, new DateTime(2020, 1, 1, 5, 10, 0)));

var groups = source
    .OrderBy(x => x.DueDate)
    .GroupConsecutive((item, group) =>
        (item.DueDate - group[0].DueDate).Duration().TotalMinutes <= 60);

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Group: {String.Join(", ", group)}");
}
```

Output:

> Group: (1, 01/01/2020 01:30:00), (2, 01/01/2020 01:40:00)
>   Group: (3, 01/01/2020 03:20:00), (4, 01/01/2020 04:10:00)
>   Group: (5, 01/01/2020 05:10:00)